# Getting Error from the following script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, compiler-errors

I am going to create SI for each record of table, getting error from stored procedure:

> No column name was specified for column 6 of 'cte_Alldates'.

Please check this script and let me know where the problem is:

[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI5at.png)

and the stored procedure:

```
create proc sp_calcualtteSI
as
begin
    DECLARE @today datetime

    SET @today = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,current_timestamp),0)

    ; WITH cte_dates AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            name, Pamount, Rateofint, cdate,
            CASE 
               WHEN ISNULL(today, @today) < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, cdate), 0))
                  THEN ISNULL(@today, @today)
               ELSE 
                  DATEADD(month, 1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, cdate), 0))
            END AS MonthEnd,
            ISNULL(@today, @today) AS End_date
        FROM 
            tbl_intestcalculate),
    cte_Alldates AS
    (
        SELECT
            name, Pamount, Rateofint, cdate, monthEnd, @today
        FROM
            cte_dates

        UNION

        SELECT 
            name, Pamount, Rateofint, 
            DATEADD(month, number, monthEnd),
            CASE 
               WHEN DATEADD(month, number + 1, monthEnd) < @today
                  THEN DATEADD(month, number + 1, monthEnd) 
                  ELSE @today
            END, 
            @today
        FROM 
            cte_dates c
        CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT number 
             FROM master..spt_values 
             WHERE type = 'p' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 11) a 
        WHERE
             dateadd(month, number, monthEnd) < @today
    )
    SELECT  
        name, cdate, monthEnd, Pamount, Rateofint,
        DATEDIFF(day, cdate, monthEnd) AS No_Of_Days,
        ROUND(Pamount * Rateofint * DATEDIFF(day, cdate, monthEnd) / 36500, 2) AS SI
    FROM
        cte_Alldates
END
```

Comment: Please **post** table and stored procedure here - as properly formatted text - don't just post screenshot of them.....

Comment: please solve as soon as

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Errr, the error message IS the solution. `@today` is a value, what "column" name doe you want it to have ?

Answer (score 1):

A CTE needs to have column names specified for all columns. In this case you are missing a column name for the sixth column. Your `cte_Alldates` CTE should read:

```
cte_Alldates AS
(
    SELECT
        name, Pamount, Rateofint, cdate, monthEnd, [day]=@today
    FROM
        cte_dates

    UNION

    SELECT 
        name, Pamount, Rateofint, 
        DATEADD(month, number, monthEnd),
        CASE 
           WHEN DATEADD(month, number + 1, monthEnd) < @today
              THEN DATEADD(month, number + 1, monthEnd) 
              ELSE @today
        END, 
        [day]=@today
    FROM 
        cte_dates c
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT number 
         FROM master..spt_values 
         WHERE type = 'p' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 11) a 
    WHERE
         dateadd(month, number, monthEnd) < @today
)
```